# Improving latency times for EC2 from different geographic areas

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load, load-balancing

We have an EC2 instance in US East, and our latency for users in the UK + AU is about 1-2 seconds higher. We are only dealing with text data and an RDS server in the same zone. Provided we want to go the route of creating another image instance of the primary EC2. How does the process work in lowering latency? Per our understanding:

- Create a replica from the image in AU/UK zones
- Add the external IP's of these two servers to the domain nameserver which will automatically generally help route the user to the closest server?
- Or does it involve creating some sort of load balancer with a geographic rule, and the load balancer IP is what our NS will be?

TLDR: How do we route UK users to the UK EC2 server, what does the setup look like?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use [Latency-based routing - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-latency.html):

> If your application is hosted in multiple AWS Regions, you can improve performance for your users by serving their requests from the AWS Region that provides the lowest latency.

You would configure one DNS Name to route to multiple IP addresses. Route 53 will examine the location of the incoming request and route the traffic to the destination with the **lowest latency**.

This is not quite the same as **geographic routing** because some countries have better Internet connectivity and traffic will be routed according to *latency* rather than *distance*.

Alternatively, you can use [AWS Global Accelerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/what-is-global-accelerator.html), which routes traffic across the AWS global network. It uses a single IP address that exists in multiple locations (known as *anycast*) to redirect traffic to the closest (fewest-hop) endpoint of the AWS global network, then sends traffic over that network to the closest AWS location where you have provisioned services. This can achieve lower latency than routing across the Internet, but incurs a **per GB cost** for traffic.

Comment: I should add we are using cloudflare for DNS, but that shouldn't make a difference if the NS resolves to the Route 53 IP correct?

Comment: Latency-based Routing and AWS Global Accelerator both require Amazon Route 53 for DNS resolution.

Comment: Ok, any alternative solutions we can use as this wouldn't work for us due to CloudFlare DNS.

Comment: You could configure the DNS record in CloudFlare as a `CNAME` record pointing to a different DNS name that is managed by Route 53. This will 'restart' the DNS resolution process with the new DNS name, allowing Route 53 to resolve the DNS name.